# Pivot String values on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have table with values, described as:

```
select top(4) Name_Country From DBO.Country
```

| Name_Country |
| --- |
| USA |
| ENGLAND |
| ITALY |
| GERMANY |

I need values in pivot format as:

| NAME_1 | NAME_2 | NAME_3 | NAME_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ENGLAND | ITALY | GERMANY |

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried , but i can't understand about this solution

Comment: then please show us what you tried the highest answer is exactly what you need

Comment: "When you use TOP with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows. Otherwise, TOP returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order."  (see" [docs for TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to generate a `ROW_NUMBER()` using the table insert order `(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))`, however, you should `ORDER BY` an actual column in your table. Your table should have a key you can use for this step.

Add more `NAME_x` row number columns to include more pivoted results:

```
SELECT 
         MAX(CASE WHEN a.rn = 1 THEN a.Name_Country END) AS NAME_1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN a.rn = 2 THEN a.Name_Country END) AS NAME_2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN a.rn = 3 THEN a.Name_Country END) AS NAME_3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN a.rn = 4 THEN a.Name_Country END) AS NAME_4
    FROM (SELECT b.Name_Country,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
            FROM Country b) a
```

**Result**

| NAME_1 | NAME_2 | NAME_3 | NAME_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ENGLAND | ITALY | GERMANY |

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MPvOAFJ0?hide=16).

Answer (score 1):

```
select [1] as NAME_1
      ,[2] as NAME_2
      ,[3] as NAME_3
      ,[4] as NAME_4
from  (
       select *
              ,row_number() over(order by Name_Country desc) as rn
       from   t
       ) t 
       pivot(max(Name_Country) for rn in([1],[2],[3],[4])) p
```

| NAME_1 | NAME_2 | NAME_3 | NAME_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ITALY | GERMANY | ENGLAND |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u3TKMMb8?hide=4)